# How do I get the closed form of this recurrence using generating functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Recurrence: $T(n) = n + nT(n-1)$ and $T(0) = 0$.

What I tried:

Let $G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T(n) x^n$ so that $xG'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nT(n)x^n$

Solving:

\begin{align}
G(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T(n) x^n 
\\&= 0x^0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T(n) x^n 
\\&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nT(n-1) x^n 
\\&= -0x^0 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^n + x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nT(n-1) x^{n-1} 
\\&= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} + x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)T(n) x^{n} 
\\&= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} + x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nT(n) x^{n} + x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T(n) x^{n} 
\\&= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} + x^2G'(x) + xG(x) 
\end{align}

And $G(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} + x^2G'(x) + xG(x)$ rearranges to $G(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^3} + \frac{x^2}{1-x}G'(x)$

No idea where to take it from here.

Comment: See here: https://oeis.org/A007526

Comment: @Kelenner I already know how to solve it by unrolling, $T(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{k!}$. But I want to use generating functions.

Comment: @RobertZ I am indeed aware of the OEIS sequence. However, I would like to use generating functions to solve this.

Comment: @Aruka J OEIS gives you also generating functions (see G.f.)

Comment: @Arukaj: In the second line after Solving, you write $nT(n)x^n$. Is it not $nT(n-1)x^n$ ?

Comment: @Kelenner You're right, thanks for seeing the error, fixed it

Comment: But now your differential equation is not correct....I think that $\sum nT(n-1)x^n=x(xG(x))^{\prime}=x^2G^{\prime}(x)+xG(x)$

Comment: @Kelenner I think I fixed it now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$G(x)-xG'(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Now use the fact that 
$$\left(\frac{G(x)}{x} \right)'=\frac{G'(x) x -G(x)}{x^2}$$

to reduce your equation to 
$$\left(\frac{G(x)}{x} \right)'=-\frac{1}{x (1-x)^2}$$

Integrate and you are done.

**Edit** To address the updated question:
$$  G'(x) -\frac{1-x}{x^2}G(x) =-\frac{1}{x(1-x)^2} $$
is a first order linear differential equation.

You can solve it by using the method listed in these notes:

[Linear Differential Equations](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand how you are going from one step to the next or how you noticed what needs to be done

Comment: @ArukaJ Which step you don't undrstand?

Comment: I understand step 1 is a rearrangement of terms. But how do you then know to use quotient rule here? Did you just look at it and "notice" it looked similar? Or is there a more methodical way to come at these problems without noticing some trick?

Comment: @ArukaJ $G(x)-xG'(x)$ reminded me of the product rule, but when you derivate $x G(x)$ you get plus instead of minus. So I used the quotient rule to change the sign.

Comment: @ArukaJ Alternately, if you are familiar, this is a linear Differential equation, and I solved it by using an integrating factor.

Comment: I'm with you there, but let's say you didn't "notice" or get "reminded" of some shortcut trick. For example if it were $x^2G'(x)$ where the product/quotient rule shortcut doesn't apply for example (not saying to solve this, just using it as an example). What's the more general way?

Comment: @ArukaJ As I said this is a Differential equation, which is linear. See http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx

Comment: $G(x) = x(1/(x-1) + \log(x-1) - \log(x))$? How do I translate that back into coefficients for $T(n)$?

Comment: @ArukaJ Write the Taylor series at $0$ for each function ;)

Comment: I am not sure how I can get that to work, because there is $\log(x-1)$ involved so I can't take the log of a negative number. It also becomes really complex really fast as I take more derivatives of the whole thing.

Comment: @ArukaJ Remember that the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x-1}$ around $0$ is NOT $\log(x-1)$. It is $\log|x-1|$. You forgot the absolute value. Around zero this becomes $\log(1-x)$. Note that your antiderivative, the way you wrote it, is undefined at $0$.

Comment: As it turns out my equation was actually wrong to begin with

Comment: @ArukaJ See the edit

Comment: Why did you negate and multiply by the inverse of the coefficient of $G'(x)$?

Comment: @ArukaJ To get the DE in standard form. Check the link.

Comment: Not familiar with the notation; which pieces go to which parts of $dy/dt + p(t)y = g(t)$? I don't see anything like $p'(t)$ here

Comment: I think I am in over my head here. The closed form according to Wolfram Alpha is not pretty: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=G%27%28x%29+-+%281-x%29*G%28x%29%2Fx^2+%3D+-1%2F%28x*%281-x%29^2%29

Comment: @ArukaJ Here we have $x$ instead of $t$ and $G(x)$ instead of $y$. In the notation of the link, your DE is $$\frac{dy}{dt}+ \frac{t-1}{t^2}y =-\frac{1}{t(1-t)^2}$$

Comment: I have to learn more about DE but thanks for the clarification, I see now why it was changed that way. Solving it though may be too complex to do by hand. I'll just have to accept that this problem is not best suited for generating functions.